# finite subset topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $X$ be a set and $\tau=\left\{X\right\}\,\cup\,\{u_i\subset X|u_i \text{ is finite}\}$. Is $\tau$ is a topology on $X$?

My effort to show this is as follows:

1) $X\in\tau$ by definition and since there are no elements in $\phi$, we have $\phi$ is finite and therefore in $\tau$.

2) If $\{u_i|i=1,\ldots,n\}$ is a finite collection of sets in $\tau$ and we know that a finite intersection of finite sets is again finite, indeed the intersection is the $u_i$ containing the least number of elements, then we know that $\bigcap_{i=1}^nu_i$ is finite and therefore in $\tau$.

3) If $I$ is some arbitrary index set and $\{u_i|i\in I\}$ is an arbitrary collection of sets in $\tau$ then it is $\bf not$ always true that the union of these elements of $\tau$ is again in $\tau$. A counterexample could be: Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and the collection of subsets in $\tau$ be $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:|x|<n\in\mathbb{N\}}$ then the union of these sets is $\mathbb{Z}\neq\mathbb{R}
$ and is infinite.

I'm trying to be logically rigorous here so if anyone has comments about this proof I would appreciate it. Maybe it is in fact a topology and I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Because of the third reason you can say that it is not a topology unless $X$ is finite.

Comment: you should fix the definition of $\tau $.

Comment: As written, $\tau$ contains a single element: $\tau = \{X\}$. I think you probably mean "$\tau = \{X\}\cup\{U\subset X\;|\;U\textrm{ is finite }\}$" instead

Comment: @MPW yes that is what is intended here. ty

Comment: and indeed, when $X$ is finite this is the same as the discrete topology